# gem install compass doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation

I'm trying to install compass on aws instance.
I used: gem install compass, it showed:

```
Fetching: sass-3.2.19.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.2.19
Successfully installed compass-0.12.5
Parsing documentation for sass-3.2.19
Installing ri documentation for sass-3.2.19
Parsing documentation for compass-0.12.5
Done installing documentation for sass, compass after 13 seconds
2 gems installed
```

Which I suppose it was successfully installed, but when I tried:
compass, it showed: command not found;

And:

```
which compass
```

It showed not installed in /usr/bin

And hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking under:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

If not, may be you are using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) in which case it would be in some directory like this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/compass
```

To find the exact executable you can just run

```
find /usr/local/ -type f | grep compass
```

Once you find it you can just add the directory where that file is to your PATH env variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:<Whatever directory where the compass executable is>
```

Comment: yes! That what it shows! But what should I do if this is the cas

Comment: actually it's /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/compass-0.12.4/lib/compass.rb

Answer (score 0):

try these commands.first install build-essentials and ruby-dev packages to install compass without errors.

## sudo apt-get install build-essential

## sudo apt-get install ruby

## sudo apt-get install ruby-dev

## sudo gem install compass